# grid.text fails to display bold expression

Tags: r, text, r-grid

I'm trying to add bold text to a **lattice** plot using `grid.text`. When I'm supplying 'character' labels, everything works just fine. However, when I try to add an expression (in this case including Greek symbols), the text is not bold. Any help on that would be highly appreciated.

```
library(grid)

grid.newpage()
grid.text("Delta (no expression)", x = .5, y = .6, gp = gpar(fontface = "bold"))
grid.text(expression(Delta ~ "(expression)"), gp = gpar(fontface = "bold"))
```

[image: bold_non-bold_grid.text]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the expression directly in bold:

```
grid.text(expression(bold(Delta ~ "(expression)")))
```

[image]

Comment: Now that is a fast and easy solution. Thanks for the hint, works just fine!